# How to convert an application from an IIS7.0 website back to a virtual directory

Tags: iis

I can currently convert a virtual directory to an application via the iis7.0 managers interface am I able to convert it back or is the only way to  remove and remap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After much and ponderous thought, I think you need to remove the application and remap as a virtual directory.

Comment: interesting style :) but I thought as much just checking I hadn't missed something in the management interface

Answer (score 8):

Right click the application and select "Remove".

Comment: unfortuantely that doesn't solve the issue it removes the application entirely which is not what i wanted, turns out though this is the only way to do this via the interface and then remap as a vdir, so +1

Comment: If your application was hosted in a directory underneath the web site, then this remove turns it back into a plain folder, but as in your case, if its a virtual directory, then the virtual directory needs remapped. Unfortunately, I know of no other way to "descalate" an application back to just a plain vdir within the UI.